# Technology behind leapsecond2015.com

Tags: javascript, css, interactive

I'm trying to find any guidance behind how http://leapsecond2015.com/ was built. Anything to get me a start would be incredibly helpful. I know it was done by droga. I'm not worried about the actual streams but more of the movement and interactivity. I want to attempt a similar project. Not sure if this is an appropriate question for Stack but thought I would ask since I cant find anything on google.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you open the console, you can see this was done with `PixiJS v3`

It is an excellent rendering library using WebGL with canvas fallback; you can check it at http://www.pixijs.com/

Pixi provides Flash-like classes like Stage, MovieClip and Sprite.

In Addition, [Phaser](http://phaser.io/), a popular game framework is based on Pixi.